# ICE 18 and ICE50 errors while packaging my windows forms desktop application with Wix V3

Tags: wix, wix3

I have this wix code for my application -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="Viveks_Alarm_Clock" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Vivek Singh" UpgradeCode="68c68d32-7939-426c-97e5-c329f58c2076">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Viveks_Alarm_Clock" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
        <Icon Id="AlarmClockIconFile" SourceFile="..\Alarm Clock\alarmclock_alarm_3338.ico"/>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Viveks_Alarm_Clock">
                    <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="95158faf-49c8-4efc-83b0-4e2bcb0cf367">
                        <File Id="AlarmClockExe" Source="..\Alarm Clock\bin\Debug\Alarm Clock.exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
                    </Component>
                    <Component Id="ShortcutAndIconFiles" Guid="77640577-6144-4007-a287-a37f921dcdb5">
                        <Shortcut Id="startmenuViveks_Alarm_Clock" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Vivek's Alarm Clock" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Icon="AlarmClockIconFile" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                        <Shortcut Id="desktopViveks_Alarm_Clock" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="Vivek's Alarm Clock" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Icon="AlarmClockIconFile" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs" />
            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
            <ComponentRef Id="ShortcutAndIconFiles"/>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Now i'm getting ICE18 and ICE50 errors

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ICE50: Component 'ShortcutAndIconFiles' has an advertised shortcut, but a null KeyPath. Vivek's Alarm Clock C:\Users\vivek.singh\source\repos\Vivek's Alarm Clock\Product.wxs   20

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ICE18: KeyPath for Component: 'ShortcutAndIconFiles' is Directory: 'INSTALLFOLDER'. The Directory/Component pair must be listed in the CreateFolders table. Vivek's Alarm Clock C:\Users\vivek.singh\source\repos\Vivek's Alarm Clock\Product.wxs   20

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ICE50: Component 'ShortcutAndIconFiles' has an advertised shortcut, but a null KeyPath. Vivek's Alarm Clock C:\Users\vivek.singh\source\repos\Vivek's Alarm Clock\Product.wxs   20

How do I resolve them? I have tried everything. I am using wix tooset v3 extension with visual studio 2022 community edition. I encountered this problem while packaging my Alarm Clock application which i'm creating for myself using C# windows forms desktop application

I tried changing file paths, they were absolute so i made it relative. I played around with the tree structure in numerous ways like placing the  tag inside  tag and so on and so forth. I followed the structure as expected by wix guideline but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Advertised shortcuts must be placed in the same Component with the File the Shortcut targets. So, move your two Shortcut elements into the `ApplicationFiles` Component and those errors should disappear.